# Zero Margin Layout with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, layout, margin, pysimplegui

I am trying to make a layout with zero top, left and right margin in Python with PySimpleGui.

**Example code**

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Text with background color', background_color='#FF0000')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(200, 200))
```

**Code result**

[image]

**Question**

Any ideas on how to remove the left, right, and the top margin? So the text would be aligned to coordinates x=0, y=0 without the blue margin?

Could it be solved with some kind of offset or just a default-margin parameter?

Answer (score 1):

- Text → no padding: `pad=(0,0)`
- Window → no margin: `margins=(0,0)`

```py
layout = [[sg.Text('Text with background color', background_color='#FF0000', pad=(0,0))]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(200, 200), margins=(0,0))
```

[Zero margin layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8VsH.png)